# Resetting the output of Verilog code

Tags: verilog

This program displays S then off then G then off. The program works but the reset doesn't work perfectly. There is some error in the waveform. I know that the problem in the value in y when the clock comes, but I don't know how to solve it.

```
module proj200 (output wire [6:0]a2g,output wire [3:0]AN,input wire fastclk,input reset); 
wire slowclk;
wire y;
slow_clock xx(fastclk,slowclk);
yinput za(slowclk,y);
hex7segm zz(slowclk,y,reset,a2g,AN);
endmodule

module slow_clock (input wire fastclk,output wire slowclk);
reg[1:0]period_count=0;
always@(posedge fastclk)
begin

period_count<=period_count+1;

end
assign slowclk=period_count[1];

endmodule




module hex7segm (input wire slowclk,input wire y,input reset,
output reg [6:0]a2g,
output reg [3:0]AN
); 
reg[1:0]x;
always@(*)
begin
if(slowclk==1 && reset==0)
begin x=2;
AN= 4'b1110;
end
else if(slowclk==0 && reset==0)

    begin
x=y;
AN= 4'b1110;
end   

else if(reset==1&& slowclk==0)
    begin 

        x=0;
        AN= 4'b1110;
end

else if(reset==1 && slowclk==1) 
    begin 

        x=0;
        AN= 4'b1110;
        end


case(x)
0: a2g=7'b0100100;
1: a2g=7'b0100000;
2: a2g=7'b1111111;
default: a2g=7'b0100100;
endcase
end
endmodule


module yinput(input wire slowclk,output wire y);
reg[1:0]period_count=0;
always@(posedge slowclk )
begin

period_count<=period_count+1;

end
assign y=period_count[0];

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

Your reset is currently doing nothing but masking the outputs (ie, forcing `x` and `AN` to some default value). It is doing nothing to your registers containing `period_count` (which in turn determines `y` and `slowclk`). Now you need to determine if you want a synchronous (a reset that follows the clock) or asynchronous reset (a reset independent of the clock). Heres examples of both:

Synchronous

```
reg [1:0] period_count; // Dont need this initialization, a reset will do it for you
always @(posedge fastclk) begin
  if (reset)
    period_count <= 0;
  else
    period_count <= period_count+1;
end
```

Asynchronous

```
reg [1:0] period_count; // Dont need this initialization, a reset will do it for you
always @(posedge fastclk, posedge reset) begin // Note the new item in the sensitivity list
  if (reset)
    period_count <= 0;
  else
    period_count <= period_count+1;
end
```

Note that `reset` will have to become an input to your other modules and you can take `reset` out of the module its currently in as that module is just combinational. If you want some other behavior, you are going to have to clarify that.

Comment: @BaderAloraini what do you mean?

Comment: the Synchronous do I use a seperate module for it?

Comment: @BaderAloraini No, I just rewrote your own always block (of which you have 2) to implement a synchronous reset. It does not require its own module.

Comment: `

if(slowclk==1 && reset==0)
begin x=y;

end
else if(slowclk==0 && reset==0)
 
 begin
x=y;

end   

else if(reset==1&& slowclk==0)
 begin 
  
  x=y;
 
end

else if(reset==1 && slowclk==1) 
 begin 
  
  x=y;
  
  end
 
 
case(x)
2'b00: a2g=7'b0100100;
2'b01: a2g=7'b0100000;
2'b10: a2g=7'b1111111;
2'b11: a2g=7'b1111111;
default: a2g=7'b0100100;
endcase
end
module yinput
reg[1:0]period_count=0;
always@(posedge slowclk or negedge slowclk )
begin
 if(reset==0) 
period_count<=period_count+1;
 else
  period_count<=0; 
  if(period_count==4)period_count=0;  
end
assign y=period_count;
endmodule`

Comment: this is what I came up with before getting your answer. any Idea why it's wrong? . I'm assigning y always to x here

Comment: Aside from that being next to impossible to read, you added a `negedge slowclk` for some reason. Also note that `period_count` can never be 4 because it is a 2-bit num0ber, so you dont even need that if statement in there (`2'd3 + 2'd1 = 2'd0`)

Comment: `module slow_clock (input wire fastclk,output wire slowclk,input reset);
reg[1:0]period_count=0;
always@(posedge fastclk)
begin 
 if(reset)
  period_count<=0;
  
  else

period_count<=period_count+1;

end
assign slowclk=period_count[1];

endmodule

`

Comment: `module yinput(input wire fastclk,input wire slowclk,output wire y,input reset);
reg[1:0]period_count=0;
always@(posedge fastclk )
 begin 
if (reset)
    period_count <= 0;
  else
    period_count <= period_count+1;
end
assign y=period_count[0];

endmodule`

Comment: I did this if I understood you but it is still not right

Comment: `module yinput(input wire slowclk,output wire y,input reset);
reg[1:0]period_count=0;
always@(posedge slowclk )
 begin 
if (reset)
    period_count <= 0;
  else
    period_count <= period_count+1;
end
assign y=period_count[0];

endmodule`

Comment: ^I changed y module to this but still

Comment: You still havent explained what "right" is. Both of those appear to implement synchronous resets.

Comment: I mean my module is running perfectly but when I press the reset it doesn't assign the value of y to zero.which means it's not resetting.